# What can I do when the E-Mail Account I registered with gets hacked?

Tags: discussion, reporting, hacked

Is there any option to let a moderator know  that an email account or OpenID is hacked and the person is doing things like abusing or breaking rules?

In such an event, what options does the *genuine* user have?

Comment: Send out an email to `team@stackoverflow.com` - explain the issue and they will handle the situation swiftly and with great skill...

Comment: I believe that an email to the team would be appropriate here as opposed to to a mod.

Comment: @bob - why remove the `hacked` tag?  Not applicable here?

Comment: @Lix: The smell of that tag was odd...so is the smell off `[reporting]` and `[haiku]`. I just don't feel that those tags are useful in the end, it's one of these tags which provoke wrong and too localized questions, in my opinion.

Comment: @bob - fair enough...

Comment: Can't you just change it?

Comment: without log in with the associated  account we can't change it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been noted in the comments, you should send an email to team@stackexchange.com as quickly as possible, including as much information about your account as you're able to.

Naturally it'll be a bit difficult for us to confirm ownership if you've lost access to the email account you registered with. However, if you're able to give us some reasonable suspicion that you're the owner, we can quickly disable all access to the account and then work with you to confirm your identity and then regain access under a fresh set of credentials.

Obviously you should also try to regain access to your email if possible, as well as take care of changing credentials on banking and other accounts that might be using your email for verification.